# Duplicate logging in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I have the below multiprocessing code which creates a file logging handler and registers it with the root logger in the main file. The main file spawns 6 processes in my specific case, all of which are logging to the same file. My target function calls the "AuthenticationFactory" class which has logs that are being duplicated. A pattern i see is that the logs in that file are duplicated 6 times per process, hence a total of 6*7=42 times (7 because total number of processes are 1 root process+6 spawned processes). The current hierarchy of my code is as follows-

xyz

- main.py
- authentication---authentication_factory.py (this contains the factory class)
- pinger.py

Now coming to the actual code, the main file spawns 6 processes

> main.py

```
from xyz.pinger import Pinger
from xyz.authentication.authentication_factory import AuthenticationFactory
_log = logging.getLogger()

class no_daemon_process(multiprocessing.Process):
    # setting 'daemon' attribute to Fals
    def _get_daemon(self):
        return False
    def _set_daemon(self, value):
        pass
    daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)


class pool_nodaemon(multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    Process = no_daemon_process

def target(group, params):
    client = AuthenticationFactory.get_auth_client(version=2)
    client.set_client_auth(group)
    Pinger(group).run()

def main():
    log_file = os.path.join(os.environ['LOG_FILE_PATH'],'{}.log'.format(os.environ['SERVICE_NAME']))
    _log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='H', interval=6, backupCount=10)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)-15s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    _log.addHandler(handler)
    
    groups = getGroups()
    pool = pool_nodaemon(len(groups)) #in my case the len=6
    action = partial(target, params=None)
    pool.map(target, groups)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> authentication_factory.py

```
import logging

_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AuthenticationFactory():
    @staticmethod
    def get_auth_client(version=2):
        if version == 1:
            _log.debug("Instantiating v1 authenticator")
            return v1Authenticator()
        elif version == 2:
            _log.debug("Instantiating v2 authenticator")
            return v2Authenticator()
        else:
            _log.error("Bad version: {}, cannot instantiate authenticator".format(version))
            return False
```

> pinger.py

```
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Pinger():
    pass #content irrelavant
```

So in this case i see the following log printed 42 times.

`2022-08-03 20:40:22,395 xyz.authentication.authentication_factory DEBUG: Instantiating v2 authenticator`

I had the following observations-

1. Setting propagate flag to False

`_log.propagate=False` in the authentication_factory file, but then it doesn't print anything to the file, rather redirects the logs to the screen. Strange that there is no duplication in the screen logs.

2. The logs from the "pinger" file are duplicated too, but setting propagate=False in the file solves the duplication for logs in that file!

I did go through the logging cookbook which suggests a Queuehandler technique for handling multiprocess logging to a single file, however, especially based on observation #2 I have a hunch that the duplication issue is something to do with logger hierarchy and the file handlers being duplicated somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which OS you're on, but from what you've describe, I'd guess some POSIX variant. Note that if you're using `fork`-based multiprocessing, child processes inherit any logging configuration from the parent, which can lead to problems.

The [logging cookbook multiprocessing example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) doesn't just illustrate using a `QueueHandler` - it also shows [one way of] how to do logging configuration for main and worker processes in a multiple process scenario. If you study that example carefully (it's too big to reproduce here), you will see how configuration can be done correctly.

Comment: What is intriguing is the fact that I'm able to solve the duplicate logging issue for top level files under the main project (ex. pinger.py) but the issue is with nested files.